# pyodbc error in macOS

Tags: python, macos, pyodbc

I am a novice python programmer and trying to connect to a SQL Server 2017 Instance running on docker using python.

I executed the below commands to install pyodbc :

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew install --no-sandbox msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
brew link msodbcsql17
brew install unixodbc  --universal
sudo pip3 install --allow-external pyodbc --allow-unverified pyodbc pyodbc
```

When I try to connect using Python I get below error :

[image: pyodbc error]

I even restarted iPython Notebook. Still same error. 
When I run `ls -ltr in /usr/local/lib/` I get :

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 abhilashdk  admin       56 Apr  6 01:36 libmsodbcsql.17.dylib -> ../Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

for `libmsodbcsql.17.dylib`. Why is iPython Notebook not able to find libmsodbcsql.17.dylib. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.